# How do I keep the points updated after the players turn?

Tags: python

I can't make my self.points change my points variable. Every time a player has his/her turn again it just restarts the users points back to 0.

The program can be played with a minimum of 2 players and a maximum of 4.

You have 2 six sided dices that are randomly rolled. If the player get doubles both dices are added together and then multiplied by 2. The answer will be added to the points. If the fist dice is a 1 then both dices are added and then subtracted from the players points, ending the turn.

If the players does not get a double or the first dice does not get a 1 then the two dices are added together and then added to the players points. This goes on until a player reaches 100 points, ending the game.

```
import random, sys

class game():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.stop = False


    def mainloop(self):
        print("Would you like to roll the dice {}?: ".format(self.name))
        return input().lower().startswith('y')


    def playing(self, points, score):
        self.points = points
        self.score = score
        while True:
            if self.mainloop() == True:
                print("it's {} go at the game with {} points".format(self.name, self.points))
                self.rule()
                if self.points >= 100:
                    print("the winners is {} with {} many points".format(self.name, self.points))
                    sys.exit()
                print("{} your points is: {}".format(self.name, self.points))
                if self.stop == True:
                    print("###############################################################")
                    print("#####################  NEXT PLAYERS TURN  #####################")
                    print("###############################################################")
                    self.score.append(self.points)
                    return (self.score)
            else:
                self.score.append(self.points)
                return (self.score)


    def rule(self):
        question = 0
        answer = 0
        dice_1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        dice_2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        print("dice 1 is: {}".format(dice_1))
        print("dice 2 is: {}".format(dice_2))


        if dice_1 == dice_2:
            if dice_1 != 1:
                question = "({} + {}) * 2".format(dice_1, dice_2)
                answer = eval(question)
                print("add {} POINTS!!!".format(answer))
                question = ("{} + {}".format(self.points, answer))
                self.points = eval(question)
                print(self.points)



            elif dice_1 == 1:
                print("add 25 POINTS!!!")
                question = ("{} + 25".format(self.points))
                self.points = eval(question)
                print(self.points)



        elif dice_1 == 1 or dice_2 == 1:
            print("unluckly! minus the points")
            question = "{} + {}".format(dice_1, dice_2)
            answer = eval(question)
            print("{} - {}".format(self.points, answer))
            question = ("{} - {}".format(self.points, answer))
            self.points = eval(question)
            print(self.points)
            self.stop = True


        elif dice_1 != 1 or dice_2 != 1:
            print("adding points!!!")
            question = "{} + {}".format(dice_1, dice_2)
            answer = eval(question)
            print("{} + {}".format(self.points, answer))
            question = "{} + {}".format(self.points, answer)
            self.points = eval(question)
            print(self.points)
            return True





def check_letter(question):
    if question.isalpha():
        return False
    else:
        print("please input a letter")
        return True




def main():
    number = [2, 3, 4]
    players = 0
    while players not in number:
        players = int(input("how many players are there? please input a number between 2 and 4: "))

    score = []
    username = []
    for x in range(int(players)):
        name = input("what is your name?: ")
        while check_letter(name) == True:
            name = input("what is your name? please input a letter: ")
        username == username.append(name)

    for z in range(int(players)):
        score.append(0)

    while True:
        for user in username:
            for points in score:
                while True:
                    gamer = game(user)
                    gamer.playing(points, score)
                    break
                break





main()
```

Comment: In the code you have shared with us, you never write anything to `self.points`. So they will stay at 0 all the time.

Comment: Another point your method/attribute (not sure what you want) `self.false` is empty. You create a method and afterwards assign `false` (whatever that is because its not pythons `False`).

Comment: You need to store the return value of `game.playing` somewhere.

Comment: Rather edit your post than posting it here in the comment section. It's not possible to format it in the comments correctly

Comment: The code you have posted, works for me (it won't stop at 100 points, but probably you need to exchange the `==100` with `>= 100`)

Comment: i mean when the player stops his turn. the point is reset. meaning when the player has his turn again the points = 0 for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this adjustment is needed:

```py
    while True:
        for i, user in enumerate(username):
            for points in score:
                while True: # I'm not sure why you have this, if you break in the first iteration in any case
                    gamer = game(user, points)
                    new_points = gamer.playing()
                    if new_points is not None: # I was not sure if you return always the new points
                        score[i] = new_points
                    break
                break
```

another thing, you should change:

```py
    def __init__(self, name, points):
        self.name = name
        self.points = points
        self.stop_turn = False #instead of own method self.false
```

(Remove the method `self.false` and please rename the variable ;))

One time the full code (still a lot to refactor):

```py
import random, sys


class game():

    def __init__(self, name, points, score):
        self.name = name
        self.stop = False
        self.points = points
        self.score = score

    def mainloop(self):
        print("Would you like to roll the dice {}?: ".format(self.name))
        return input().lower().startswith('y')

    def playing(self):
        while True:
            if self.mainloop():
                print("it's {} go at the game with {} points".format(self.name, self.points))
                self.rule()
                if self.points >= 100:
                    print("the winners is {} with {} many points".format(self.name, self.points))
                    sys.exit()
                print("{} your points is: {}".format(self.name, self.points))
                if self.stop:
                    print("###############################################################")
                    print("#####################  NEXT PLAYERS TURN  #####################")
                    print("###############################################################")
                    # self.score.append(self.points)
                    return self.points
            else:
                # self.score.append(self.points)
                return self.points

    def rule(self):
        question = 0
        answer = 0
        dice_1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        dice_2 = random.randint(1, 6)

        print("dice 1 is: {}".format(dice_1))
        print("dice 2 is: {}".format(dice_2))

        if dice_1 == dice_2:
            if dice_1 != 1:
                question = "({} + {}) * 2".format(dice_1, dice_2)
                answer = dice_1 + dice_2
                print("add {} POINTS!!!".format(answer))
                question = ("{} + {}".format(self.points, answer))
                self.points += answer
                print(self.points)



            elif dice_1 == 1:
                print("add 25 POINTS!!!")
                question = ("{} + 25".format(self.points))
                self.points += 25
                print(self.points)



        elif dice_1 == 1 or dice_2 == 1:
            print("unluckly! minus the points")
            question = "{} + {}".format(dice_1, dice_2)
            answer = dice_1 + dice_2
            print("{} - {}".format(self.points, answer))
            question = ("{} - {}".format(self.points, answer))
            self.points -= answer
            print(self.points)
            self.stop = True


        elif dice_1 != 1 or dice_2 != 1:
            print("adding points!!!")
            question = "{} + {}".format(dice_1, dice_2)
            answer = dice_1 + dice_2
            print("{} + {}".format(self.points, answer))
            question = "{} + {}".format(self.points, answer)
            self.points += answer
            print(self.points)
            return True


def check_letter(question):
    if question.isalpha():
        return False
    else:
        print("please input a letter")
        return True


def main():
    number = [2, 3, 4]
    players = 0
    while players not in number:
        players = int(input("how many players are there? please input a number between 2 and 4: "))

    score = []
    username = []
    for x in range(int(players)):
        name = input("what is your name?: ")
        while check_letter(name) == True:
            name = input("what is your name? please input a letter: ")
        username.append(name)

    for z in range(int(players)):
        score.append(0)

    while True:
        for i, user in enumerate(username):
            gamer = game(user, score[i], score)
            print("??", score, i)
            score[i] = gamer.playing()


main()
```

Comment: sorry to ask but... how do i use the self.stop_turn. i feel a bit stupid but wanted to ask just in case

Comment: Simply replace all occurrences of `self.false` with `self.stop_turn`

Comment: i tried this sorry for the late reply but... its still not working. i thought i could work it out by learning if not none and enumerate but still don't understand. i did try putting what u said but still could not keep track of the points for a specific player? :(